# Integrating facebook connect (graph api)in cakephp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp

How I can integrate facebook graph api in cakephp for facebook login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> for facebook login

so, if you would do login to your page with facebook, probably you should use taht official JS libs: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js . With that, you could achieve facebook user id-number, so you could use it in DB as unique key which represent user.

Comment: Can you explain how i can integrate facebook graph api in cake php for facebook login..

Comment: Here is nice example: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Nick Baker's fabulous [CakePHP Facebook Plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/wtn/blogs/view/238/Facebook_Plugin_v2_0_Graph_System).